# Can new TestNG plugin ruin my perfect code using old TestNG

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

So, I had my code running fine before with no errors. I wrote it when I was using the old testng plugin for Eclipse. Now I have no way of installing this old plugin because it is no longer available on the website. I installed the latest version, but now run into all sorts of errors. Is it possible these errors are caused by new version of TestNG?

Thanks for the help. (I'm trying to run my code on new computer and reinstalled everything.)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can install any old version of the plug-in by picking an update site here:

http://beust.com/eclipse-old

Comment: Hi Cedric..changing to older plugin fixed the repeat suite running problem! I think ver6.4 has a bug

Comment: Hi Cedric, I've confirmed that plugin6.4 has a problem with repeating the test suites. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!